# Access IConfiguration in the ActionFilterAttribute in the asp.net core rc2 application

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core

I am writing attribute that will verify captcha. In order to work correctly it needs to know secret, which I keep in the settings (Secret manager tool). However I don't know how to read config from the attribute class. DI in asp.net core supports constructor injection (and property injection is not supported), so this will give compilation error:

```
public ValidateReCaptchaAttribute(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            if (configuration == null)
            {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("configuration");
            }

            this.m_configuration = configuration;
        }
```

because when I decorate method with `[ValidateReCaptcha]` I can't pass config

So how do I can read something from config from the method in attribute class?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use `ServiceFilter attribute`, more info in this [blog post](https://damienbod.com/2015/09/15/asp-net-5-action-filters/) and [asp.net docs](https://docs.asp.net/en/latest/mvc/controllers/filters.html#configuring-filters).

```
[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateReCaptchaAttribute))]
public IActionResult SomeAction()
```

In `Startup`

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
       // Add functionality to inject IOptions<T>
       services.AddOptions();

       // Add our Config object so it can be injected
       services.Configure<CaptchaSettings>(Configuration.GetSection("CaptchaSettings"));

       services.AddScoped<ValidateReCaptchaAttribute>();
       ...
}
```

And `ValidateReCaptchaAttribute`

```
public class ValidateReCaptchaAttribute : ActionFilterAttribute
{
     private readonly CaptchaSettings _settings;

     public ValidateReCaptchaAttribute(IOptions<CaptchaSettings> options)
     {
         _settings = options.Value;
     }

     public override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
     {
         ...
         base.OnActionExecuting(context);
     }
}
```

Comment: Where does IOptions come from? Is that necessary? It's not mentioned in either of the docs you linked.

Comment: @starmandeluxe This mechanism allows to inject strong typed options into services. You can find more info at Rick Strahl's [post](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/may/23/strongly-typed-configuration-settings-in-aspnet-core)

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately it doesn't work for me this way. It requires a parameterless constructor in the config object, and inside mine I need to grab settings from appSettings.json, which requires a IConfigurationRoot parameter. The result is that all the fields are null since it seems like it's not using my parameterized constructor.

Comment: @starmandeluxe I am not able to understand your issue. Its better if you make a new post

Comment: I figured it out. It requires to first use services.AddSingleton() to initialize the config instead of services.Configure()

Answer (score 5):

You should use `ServiceFilter` like this:

`[ServiceFilter(typeof(ValidateReCaptcha))]`

And if you want to use `IConfiguration` you should inject it in `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddSingleton((provider)=>
{
     return Configuration;
});
```